# Unhiding An Attribute For A Given Application in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, attributes

I had a icon on my Windows Desktop which was called "Windows 7 in a Box". It was an application which basically gave me easy access to Windows system controls aka [God Mode](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-10423985-285/understanding-windows-7s-godmode/).

I was trying to hide the file extension after the name (which was shown), but instead went into *Properties* and next to *Attributes* clicked on *Hidden*. The desktop icon has now disappeared.

A search using *search program and files* to find the program reveals nothing.

How do I unhide the attribute for that particular application and restore it back onto the Desktop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Control Panel` - `Folder Options` - Under `Hidden files and folders` select Show hidden files, folders, and drives.

That should reveal the icon on your desktop. From there you can undo the incorrect changes and apply the correct ones.

Comment: That worked thanks very much BUT one minor niggle after Control Panel you have to go to Appearances and Personalization before being directed to Folder Options

Comment: Good to hear. On the `view by` drop-down on the top-right, if you choose small or large icons, Folder options will be more easily accessible.

Comment: Excellent, I never knew that. Thanks very much.

Comment: Additionally if I goto "All Control Panel Items" which is located on my RocketDock, I can also access Folder Options from there as well.